# Video Game Auction - Logic Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

[image: StackExchange Video Game Puzzle]

> **Puzzle Difficulty**: Very Challenging

#### The Story

Johnny loves his classic video games. He has collected most of them. Unfortunately, though, Johnny's Grandmother needs an expensive operation. He has to sell his games to come up with the money.

All of his "classic" video games this week were sold via online auctions. Match each game to the year it came out and determine who bought it and for how much.

> ### Clues

**1:** Of Gator Attack and the one that came out in 1983, one was purchased by Eduardo and the other was purchased by Horace.

**2:** The one that came out in 1985, Troop Seven and the game that came out in 1986 are all different video games.

**3:** Victorforce came out 3 years after the game bought by Eduardo.

**4:** Countershot is either the one bought by Bruce or the one bought by Eduardo.

**5:** The video game bought by Virgil came out sometime before the one bought by Bruce.

**6:** The game bought by Horace came out 3 years before the game bought by Alfred.

> ### Puzzle Data

**Video Games**
-- AWOL Alert
-- Countershot
-- Gator Attack
-- Troop Seven
-- Victorforce

**Buyers**
-- Alfred
-- Bruce
-- Eduardo
-- Horace
-- Virgil

**Years**
-- 1983
-- 1984
-- 1985
-- 1986
-- 1987

> ### Puzzle Grid

[image: Puzzle Grid]

> ### Answer Grid ##
>
> [image: ANswer Grid]

** Good Luck, Puzzlers. **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the provided grid:

> [image: Solution grid]
>  (with the colours done in order, based on the information of the clues indicated)

The solution is:

> `AWOL Alert   - 1985  -  Virgil`
>  `Countershot  - 1983  -  Eduardo`
>  `Gator Attack - 1984  -  Horace`
>  `Troop Seven  - 1987  -  Alfred`
>  `Victorforce  - 1986  -  Bruce`